# When should application fail to start?

Tags: server, services, devops

What are the best practices regarding start of an application which depends on several services and maybe some file system stuff like mounts, directories or config file.

Let's say the dababase is not up or returns a fail status when the application starts. Should the application:

- fail to start and report this error or
- should it start and periodically check if database works and

  - provide services which are available without db (and report error when serving request needs db)
  - report error for any request

What about file system dependencies (e.g. stuff which you do not expect to get solved up that fast)

Does this depend on the each situation/feature/service or do you think there is a rule of thumb ?

Comment: This thing entirely depends on what app you are building and for what needs, what your client expects, etc. It's a huge "depends". Also, "What is the best.." type of questions are generally not quite on topic.

Answer (score 1):

As almost always in software development, the answer is "it depends".

Depends upon your requirements of resiliency, what kind of resources you're trying to acquire, what's the expected availability of those resources, etc. etc. etc.

Two good guidelines usually are [Fail Fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) and also [Fail Fast](https://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf), where your application fails and stops as soon as it can't acquire your specified resource, and points on the logging system or console why did it fail, giving the operator the chance to correct a problem.

But what if you're writing a daemon/service that runs in background 24x7 and tries to web-scrape some information from a website that is half the day up and half the day down ?

And the other question is, what happens during the running life of your application if a resource you take for granted just disappears, like memory (with several OutOfMemoryException lying around) or database or disk space ?

Depending on the resiliency requirements of your solution, you must handle these exceptional conditions accordingly.

A one-time only application that is fired just to run a report or crunch some data and cannot connect on the database at start may fail fast.

A web-application GUI that's the one-stop-shop for your user should handle this gracefully in order to provide the user with better experience.